# 64 bit OS with 32 bit MS office issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C#.net application.

I have developed window application, which uses the access database.

When i am running my application in 32 bit OS and 32 bit MS office its working fine.

The same way its running in 64 bit OS and 64 bit MS office.

But when i am trying to run in 64 bit os with 32 bit MS office , its throwing following error

> *"System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
>   provider is not registered on the local machine........."*

Why this execption occur and what is the soltuion for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this post: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1348126.aspx

There are loads of information about that issue on the web, read a bit around and you'll find the solution

Also try changing the Compile configuration to x86.

Comment: Keeping the configuration at x86 means that it will always be a 32 bit app.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this may solve your problem
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734